# ManagedTaskListener don't work

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, executorservice

I'm tying to implement an asyncronous test launcher for a Java EE app develop in java but my ManagedTaskListener implementation don't "listen" events.

I have this test implementation:

```
package com.co.seti.sima.commons.executor;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService;
import javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedTaskListener;

public class TestLauncher implements Callable<ResultadoPruebaDTO>, ManagedTaskListener {


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedTaskListener#taskAborted(java.util.concurrent.Future, javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Throwable)
     */
    public void taskAborted(Future<?> arg0, ManagedExecutorService arg1, Object arg2, Throwable arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Se obortó la ejecucion");

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedTaskListener#taskDone(java.util.concurrent.Future, javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Throwable)
     */
    public void taskDone(Future<?> arg0, ManagedExecutorService arg1, Object arg2, Throwable arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Tark done");
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedTaskListener#taskStarting(java.util.concurrent.Future, javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService, java.lang.Object)
     */
    public void taskStarting(Future<?> arg0, ManagedExecutorService arg1, Object arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Starting task");
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedTaskListener#taskSubmitted(java.util.concurrent.Future, javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService, java.lang.Object)
     */
    public void taskSubmitted(Future<?> arg0, ManagedExecutorService arg1, Object arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Task submit");
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.util.concurrent.Callable#call()
     */
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Task Executed";
    }
}
```

And i use it on an EJB Singleton

```
@Resource
private ManagedExecutorService managedExecutorService;

...

managedExecutorService.submit(new TestLauncher());

...
```

The excution starts and finish fine but the listener don't log events.

I don't understant, please help.

Comment: Why does your task implement `ManagedTaskListener`? I believe it should implement `ManagedTask` according to [this](https://concurrency-ee-spec.java.net/javadoc/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html) doc "*Tasks can optionally provide an ManagedTaskListener to receive notifications of lifecycle events, through the use of ManagedTask interface*". Try creating second class for a listener and make your `TestLauncher` implement [`ManagedTask`](https://concurrency-ee-spec.java.net/javadoc/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedTask.html).

Comment: @Geinmachi You should just make that an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a class with the ManagedTaskListener and ManagedTask. this clase can be Callable or Runnable.

```
private static class DukeMessage implements ManagedTask, ManagedTaskListener, Callable<Long> {

    private final ChatMessage cmsg;
    private final Session session;

    public DukeMessage(ChatMessage cmsg, Session session) {
        this.cmsg = cmsg;
        this.session = session;
    }

    public synchronized void sendAll(Session session, Object msg) {
        try {
            for (Session s : session.getOpenSessions()) {
                if (s.isOpen()) {
                    s.getBasicRemote().sendObject(msg);
                    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Sent: {0}", msg.toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | EncodeException e) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ManagedTaskListener getManagedTaskListener() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getExecutionProperties() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Long call() throws Exception {
        try {
            String resp = "Respuesta de Duke!";
            //botbean.respond(cmsg.getMessage());
            sendAll(session, new ChatMessage("Duke", cmsg.getName(), resp));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return 0L;
    }

    //@Override
    //public void run() {
        //try {
            //String resp = "Respuesta de Duke!";
            //botbean.respond(cmsg.getMessage());
            //sendAll(session, new ChatMessage("Duke", cmsg.getName(), //resp));
        //} catch (Exception ex) {
            //System.out.println(ex);
        //}
    //}

    @Override
    public void taskSubmitted(Future<?> future, ManagedExecutorService executor, Object task) {
        System.out.println("taskSubmitted");
    }

    @Override
    public void taskAborted(Future<?> future, ManagedExecutorService executor, Object task, Throwable exception) {
        System.out.println("taskAborted");
    }

    @Override
    public void taskDone(Future<?> future, ManagedExecutorService executor, Object task, Throwable exception) {
        System.out.println("taskDone");
    }

    @Override
    public void taskStarting(Future<?> future, ManagedExecutorService executor, Object task) {
        System.out.println("taskStarting");
    }

}
```

The call will be ...

```
mes.submit(new DukeMessage(cmsg, session));
```

or

```
mes.execute(new DukeMessage(cmsg, session));
```

Comment: will Listener work for invokeAll() ?. or only for submit and execute. it is not working for invokeAll()

Comment: it works for only for submit and execute. not for invokeAll.